# Regular expression ignores results after newline

Tags: java

I need to add an underscore before words that repeat more than once in text using regular expressions.

So what I have right now is :

```
    (\b[a-zA-Z]+)(?=\s+\1)
```

And sample string is:

```
    This is a test test
    And this is also a test
    And these are also working working tests
```

The expected result is:

```
    This _is _a _test _test
    _And this _is _also _a _test
    _And these are _also _working _working tests
```

But i get:

```
    This is a _test _test
    And this is also a _test
    And these are also _working _working tests
```

Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "This is a test test\n" +
            "And this is also a test\n" +
            "And these are also working working tests\n";

    String regex = "(\\b[a-zA-Z]+)(?=\\s+\\1)";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

    while (m.find()) {
        input = input.replaceAll("\\b"+m.group(0)+"\\b", "_" + m.group(0));
    }
    System.out.println(input);
}
```

So, it works perfectly fine on a span of one line and regex finds words only if they are repeated on that exact line only then it marks that words on others lines. But if two words are repeated on two different lines it ignores them. I'm out of ideas why this happens and I need help...
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem isn't because of newlines; its because your regex only matches words that appear immediately next to each other, with just whitespace in between the two occurrences.

The regex `\b([a-zA-Z]+)\b(?=.*\b\1\b)` will do what you want, because the `.*` allows any text to appear between the two occurrences of the word. That said, newlines do matter, because by default `.` matches any character *except* a newline; so you need to write `Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL)` in order for it to work how you want.